# first toggle div needs to start open

Tags: html, load, toggle, hide, show

i have groupings of 2 divs ('question' and 'answer').
when 'question' is clicked, 'answer' shows.
when 'question' is clicked again (or another 'question' is clicked), the currently visible 'answer' hides and the new one shows.
what i can't figure out is how to make the first question/answer set of the series show on page load

code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".answer").hide();
    jQuery(".question").click(function() {
        jQuery(".answer").not(jQuery(this).next(".answer")).hide();
        jQuery(this).next(".answer").toggle();
    });
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pixeloco/Y724r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trigger a click on `first-child`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery(".answer").hide();
    jQuery(".question").click(function () {
        jQuery(".answer").not(jQuery(this).next(".answer")).hide();
        jQuery(this).next(".answer").toggle();
    });
    jQuery('.question:first-child').trigger('click');
});
```

[Check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y724r/1/)